# How secure is free-space optical communication?

Tags: network

I just read an interesting history about "Ronja" (J. Soederberg, "Users in the Dark", in G. Alberts, R. Oldenziel (Ed.), Hacking Europe (Springer Verlag, 2014)) of an earlier optical network in the Czech Republic using red light and later infra-red light.

More general info on that type of communication can be found in the wiki article on Free-space_optical_communication. As a layman, I surmise that with the best techniques available today (perhaps certain special lasers) and eventually via a satellite to overcome the curvature of the Earth, correct and fast transmission of information between two arbitrary locations is feasible this way.

Could someone say something concerning the security of such optical networks, i.e. possibilities of eventual leakages of information to the adversaries, disturbance attacks, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking here. This is already done at various frequencies.

If you are wondering whether or not an adversary can detect the signal, then yes, absolutely. Treat it like wireless comms and encrypt everything you need to secure.

Denial of service through jamming is also possible - use a powerful enough source and you can jam most things. Whether or not jamming laser comms is a valid attack is another question - if you were in position to do it there would probably be simpler attacks, like putting an opaque object in the way.

If your two locations are close, then you'd be more secure running optical fibre underground between the buildings, but in any case, interception is possible with all comms (with the possible exception of Quantum Entanglement - where interception will change the data)

Comment: I am specially interested to know something in the present context of laser communications. Could you kindly give some references that are helpful for me?

Comment: what is that 'something'? If it's around whether a laser signal can be intercepted, then yes of course - even just at the moon's distance, a laser hits a large area ( At the Moon's surface, the beam is about 6.5 kilometers wide - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment )

Comment: But on Earth, between two stations that are not two far part, one could arrange to avoid interception or not?

Comment: Okay - if you are not talking about the satellite bit, then sure - at closer distances, the spread of a laser will be much less, but remember that any attacker could move into the direct line of sight, so my original point still stands - encrypt it if it is sensitive info.